# How to correctly set the zi parameter (initial condition) for a scipy IIR filter

Tags: filters, filter-design, python, scipy

Let's take as an example an IIR filter using the 'sos' output, as this is what I use the most. To apply a bandpass filter, you can do:

```
from scipy.signal import butter, sosfilt

fs = 512 # Sampling rate, Hz
lowcut = 1 # Hz, cutting frequency
highcut = 40 # Hz, currting frequency

low = lowcut / (0.5 * fs)
high = highcut / (0.5 * fs)
sos = butter(2, [low, high], btype='band', output='sos', fs=fs)

data = sosfilt(sos, data)
```

This is great. Now let's consider that our data is not a simple 1D example, but instead a 2D array of `N` channels sampled during 1 second. Thus, with `data.shape = samples x channels` the last line becomes:

```
data = sosfilt(sos, data, axis=0)
```

Now, what if we want to take into account the initial condition? Then, the `zi` argument must be provided. The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.sosfilt.html) says:

> Initial conditions for the cascaded filter delays. It is a (at least
> 2D) vector of shape (n_sections, ..., 2, ...), where ..., 2, ...
> denotes the shape of x, but with x.shape[axis] replaced by 2. If zi is
> None or is not given then initial rest (i.e. all zeros) is assumed.

Thus, if we want to reproduce the 'None' behavior, using an initial rest, and returning the `zf` (final filter decay value), `zi` can be initialized with `np.zeros((sos.shape[0], 2, N))` for the data example above of shape `samples x channels`.

> zf: ndarray, optional
>
> If zi is None, this is not returned, otherwise, zf holds the final filter delay values.

All this makes sense. **But then what about a non-resting-state initial condition?**
That is where the function `scipy.signal.sosfilt_zi()` should come into play. But I don't understand what it does, and how it determines initial conditions from the `sos` argument and not from the actual signal to filter.

Moreover, it returns a `zi` of shape `(n_sections, 2)` which is only good for the 1D case. What about a multidimensional array filtered along an axis? How should the `zi` returned by `scipy.signal.sosfilt_zi()` be used to create a `(n_sections, ..., 2, ...)` array?

Comment: I went down this path -- take a look at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/86883/using-scipy-signal-sosfilt-to-filter-a-stereo-signal-with-zi-zf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I don't understand what it does, and how it determines initial conditions from the sos argument and not from the actual signal to filter.

From the documentation

> Compute an initial state zi for the sosfilt function that corresponds
> to the steady state of the step response.

It assumes that the input signal is a unit step. That's useful if you input signal has a large DC offset (at least in the beginning). You can call `sosfilt_zi()`, multiply it with the DC offset and apply it as state.

> What about a multidimensional array filtered along an axis?

You need to determine the initial DC offset or bias of each channel individually and cascade the results of `sosfilt_zi()*bias` for each channel.

Comment: Ok, so this is completely useless in the case of a signal which does not look like a unit test. In the case of a more general signal, I should keep using a zero-initialized `zi`?

Comment: No. Initialize with the mean of of the first N samples, where N is roughly the length of the impulse response of the filter or where the bias is reasonably constant.

Comment: @Mathieu In the case of a more general signal, then you should use *that signal* to generate `zi`, no?

Comment: @endolith That is what I thought too. Hilmar gave me a second answer on a different related question where I show a raw signal with a very large DC bias. zi can be multiplied with the DC bias to get the correct zi for my signal.

Comment: @endolith the trick here is that you need to make a guess what the signal was earlier, so you need to extrapolate backwards in time.  If you don't specify `zi` the filter  function will assume that the signal has been zero before the first sample. This may or may not be a good assumption. In case of a large DC bias it's clearly NOT a good assumption.